# How to hide next n lines from the current line interactively

Tags: vim, fold

I have a two large tables in a single text file, one below the other. I want to compare them manually line by line.

Each table is very big and I need to scroll a lot. In Vim, can I hide the next N lines from the current line interactively, so that both the lines which I need to compare can be seen on a single screen, and as I move the cursor to the next line, the next N lines should get folded.

In short I want to drag the fold up and down.

Comment: Open the file in 2 split windows, vertical or horizontal.

Comment: this is not the solution you want, however check out
```
:help jumplist
```
it might help you with your scrolling 
also I personally like to write functions with little white lines, it enables me to quicky jump paragraphs(functions) with '{' and '}'

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question.  Say the file is 1000 lines, and you want to compare sections that are 200 lines apart -- say, compare line 400 with line 600, and line 401 with line 601, etc.  So you want to fold lines 401 - 599, then when you "j" down a line, the fold moves to lines 402 - 600.  If that's what you're looking for, I'm not aware of it in stock Vim; I use a split window for that kind of thing, as @phd suggested.  It sounds useful though, so maybe someone may have programmed it in VimScript or a plugin package.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"

Comment: Did you try `vimdff`?

Comment: @m_mlv Yes, I wanted to do exactly same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hiding lines is the wrong tool for the job. You want scroll binding (`:help scroll-binding`).

```
:e file.txt
:set scb
:vsp file.txt
:201
:set scb
```

This sequence will allow you to open your `file.txt` in two windows, scroll-bound, with 200 lines apart. If you want to split windows horisontally, replace `:vsp` with `:sp`. If you want to adjust the offset, either use the mouse scroll on the non-active window, or turn off scroll-binding in one window, adjust cursor, then reactivate scroll-binding:

```
:set noscb
20j
:set scb
```

Comment: Agreed about scroll binding. Open two views into the same file and scroll away